# Elgg -- Create a default widget

Tags: elgg

I need to create a widget as a default one for he profile page in Elgg Site .
I just tried with the docs and some default widget plugins, But unfortunately i need to make it by code, and cant use any plugin.

Can anyone help me in creating such a widget

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know its late. But this is an easier thing.
For plugin based solutions you can try the default_widgets plugin you receive with the download package or the widget manager plugin from coldtrick (Available in the elgg community).
If you can't use a plugin for this functionality,

- Create a plugin hook for user registration event
- use the elgg_create_widget() to add the widget
- Override the widget view so that you can remove the widget controls.

But you still need a plugin to develop this.